# How to start LXDE on Fedora Server?

Tags: fedora, gui, lxde

I have Fedora Server 22 installed on my server.

I installed LXDE with:

```
sudo dnf groupinstall "LXDE Desktop"
```

And rebooted. But it started in text mode.

How do I start LXDE?

### Update

`startx` gives me the following error:

[image]

```
xauth: file /home/<myuser>/.serverauth.<ramdomnumber> does not exists
```

Comment: When logged in the 'text mode', try to type startx. If this does not work, try startlxde. Tell me if this work for you

Comment: @Ob1lan thank you helping. See the picture, `startx` gives me a error, `startlxde` gives me "Command not found".